# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify with java 11

Tags: java-11, apache-httpcomponents

I am getting the following exception on calling close on the http response on java 11. This used to work with java 8.

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:269)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:260)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:737)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:716)
    at org.apache.http.impl.BHttpConnectionBase.close(BHttpConnectionBase.java:327)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection.close(LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection.java:81)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolEntry.closeConnection(CPoolEntry.java:70)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.close(CPoolProxy.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ConnectionHolder.releaseConnection(ConnectionHolder.java:103)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ConnectionHolder.close(ConnectionHolder.java:156)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.HttpResponseProxy.close(HttpResponseProxy.java:62)
```

The above exception happens on calling response.close() in the below code:

```
    HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(url);
    CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        response = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line = "";
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         // do something with the line
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (response != null) {
            response.close();
        }
        if (reader != null) {
            reader.close();
        }
    }
```

I am using httpclient 4.5.3.
I observe the same error on reader.close() as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It indeed was an issue with the wrong order of closing. Closed the reader first and then connection and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to close the request and the reader in the wrong order. In my opinion you should better reformat the code to use try-with-resource blocks that automatically close the resource so that you can never again run into this problem:

```
HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(url);
try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpRequest)) {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()))) {
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // do something with the line
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw e;
}
```